# What is the best way to get the name of a static library an object file belongs to in C or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, static-libraries

I'm creating some static libraries (MyLib, OtherLib) that contain C or Objective-C code, and I'd like each module to be able to access the name of the static library.

I could do a

```
const char* mylibname = "MyLib";
```

and use it everywhere. However, I want a more convenient method, where each file in every library can access its library through constant `currentlibname`. So when a file is in MyLib, `currentlibname`´s value is "MyLib", when it is in OtherLib, its value is "OtherLib".

Any ideas on the most convenient solution? Ideally all the magic should be in one place, without the need to adjust every file besides including something that declares `mylibname`.

Regards,
Jochen

Comment: Micro-optimization: use `const char mylibname[] = "Mylib";` which saves you the size of a pointer in storage space.

Comment: Since the association of source code (or even object files) with libraries is largely arbitrary, it is difficult to avoid a largely manual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It obviously depends upon the operating system, the compiler, the builder.

If you've got dynamic libraries on Linux, you could retrieve at runtime some information, perhaps thru `/proc/self/maps` and maybe `dladdr` (and perhaps even [return address builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html)).

My suggestion would be to define a preprocessor symbol during the building of each library, perhaps with something like `CFLAGS += -DTHIS_LIBRARY_NAME=MyLib` in your `Makefile` and have in `mylib.h` something using it. For C I might suggest to put in `mylib.h` something like

```
#define QUOTE_NAME(N) #N
static inline const char *this_library_name () 
{ return QUOTE_NAME(THIS_LIBRARY_NAME); }
```

BTW, you could even put the above code in a common single header file included by your libraries main header file.

But I am a bit surprised you ask that. A better way might be to give an API for the version of your library, see what [gtk does about feature tests](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Feature-Test-Macros.html).